# splitting a column and accessing the resulting list

Tags: pandas

I have a dataframe called standard, with a column named '# genes'. I'd like to split that one and assign elements of the resulting list to a new column. That is, it looks like this:

```
standard['# genes'].str.split("+")
0     [3798 ,  144 part]
1     [3556 ,  138 part]
2     [3783 ,  135 part]
3     [3974 ,  115 part]
4     [3813 ,  135 part]
5     [3830 ,  141 part]
6     [3944 ,  128 part]
7     [3926 ,  129 part]
8     [3803 ,  126 part]
9     [3838 ,  127 part]
10    [3732 ,  141 part]
Name: # genes, dtype: object
```

Thus, I'd like to be able to assign 3798, 3556, 3783 and so on to a new column in standard. However, I have not been able to comprehend enough of indexing in pandas to understand how to get to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use parameter `expand=True` to [`split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html) for convert `list`s to columns:

```
df = standard['# genes'].str.split("+", expand=True)
```

If want add 2 new columns to original DataFrame:

```
standard[['a','b']] = standard['# genes'].str.split("+", expand=True)
```